# Identify my specific client machine over ssh to server

Tags: bash, ssh

I share a dev server/environment with a few other engineers, and we all share a user account on that server.

I use it often enough that I'd like to do some configuration via .bashrc, but I don't want to have those changes affect everyone else using the account. Ideally I'd like to do something like:

```
if [ "$SSH_CLIENT_USER" = "<me>" ]; then
    # do my config
fi
```

Are there any such environment variables set by ssh that might be used to uniquely identify me? Or any other way of differentiating client machines? Maybe some ssh configuration I could do with my laptop to have it identify itself? I don't have admin rights to the server (and wouldn't want to use them anyway) but of course I'm open to making any changes to my laptop's configuration.

Comment: [Why is sharing a user a bad habit?](http://serverfault.com/q/755373/186199)

Comment: Yes, I agree it's not a good situation. But I'm not the one setting up and admin-ing the server. I could try to get them to change it, but that's slow and unlikely to actually happen; I'd prefer if possible to work this out on my end.

Answer (score 2):

Jakuje had a lot of good ideas that unfortunately all didn't work for different reasons, but the suggestion about agent forwarding gave me an idea that does work.

`ssh-add -l` lists available agents, and since my key is stored in my laptop's home directory which contains my unique work id, I was able to use that:

```
if [[ $(ssh-add -l 2> /dev/null) == *"<my-id>"* ]]; then
    # do my config
fi
```

(Paired with `ForwardAgent yes` in my local `~/.ssh/config`)

Comment: good idea in working around workarounds of workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Manual page for [`ssh`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) provides some possible answers. There are many different variables, from which this one might be interesting for you:

#### If you connect always from the same IP address (or from finite set), you can use

> ```
> SSH_CONNECTION
> ```
>
> Identifies the client and server ends of the connection.  The variable contains four space-separated values: client IP address, client port number, server IP address, and server port number.

#### You can define your variables

I hope you are using ssh keys for authentication. If you might prefix your key with modifier in `authorized_keys` file, to define another environment variable, such as:

```
environment="WHOIAM=my-mane" ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza...LiPk== user@example.net
```

and then you can check this variable in the `~/.bashrc`. As described in manual page for [`sshd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd)

#### You can pass the variables from client

If you would have access to server configuration, you might configure both client and server to send and accept some environment variable of your choice (`SendEnv` and `AcceptEnv` options).

#### You can detect special configuration

Other ideas might be to use `ssh-agent` forwarding (if you know that colleagues do not use it) and check for variable `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.

Comment: These are good ideas, but most of us often connect from behind the same NAT, and others do use agent forwarding.

Comment: Added another possibility, which should help you - prefix your keys in `authorized_keys` file. This should have no drawback, but leaving even the other for reference.

Comment: Unfortunately we all share the same key. I know it's bad practice, but I don't control it.

Comment: And you don't even have write access to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to create new one? It is not only bad practice, but it is very bad practice. Then you will probably have to create local alias such as `alias ssh-host="ssh -tt host bash --rcfile your.bashrc"`. It is not elegant, it will not work for all cases, but it should solve the case of interactive shells.

Comment: Centrally managed keys are not bad practice, sharing a private key is. Better concatenate the engeneers' public keys in authorized_keys, prefixed with the environment phrase mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind messing with you local SSH command (that you run on your machine to connect to the server), then you can execute it like this:

```
ssh user@remote -t 'export SPECIAL_ID=magic; bash -l'
```

(Obviously you'd want to put this in a script or shell alias).

This will start a new shell, very much like you normally do, but first set an environment variable that you can then check in `.bashrc` and friends.

Another way to achieve the same effect is to set the `SendEnv` option in your `.ssh/config` file, but that would also require you to be able to set the appropriate `AcceptEnv` option in the server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, which may not be possible if you don't have administrator rights on the server - so the above solution would provide the same effect without needing administrator rights on the server.